# Как можно улучшить код бинарного поиска?

Tags: c

Как можно улучшить данный код?

```
//бинарный поиск
bool binary_search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int min, max, med, i;
    min = 0;
    max = n;
    med = max/2;
    i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(values[med] > value)
        {
            max = med;
            med /= 2;
        }
        else if(values[med] < value)
        {
            min = med;
            med = (min + max)/2;
        }
        else if(values[med] == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(i == n)
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, `max = n;` обеспечивает вам возможность выхода за границу массива... Еще очень странная у вас проверка `if (i == n)` - т.е. вы бинарнгый поиск превращаете в линейный :)

Comment: К тому же бинарный поиск пишется намного короче.

Comment: Используйте для поиска среднего формулу  (begin + (end-begin)/2), чтобы избежать переполнения. https://thebittheories.com/the-curious-case-of-binary-search-the-famous-bug-that-remained-undetected-for-20-years-973e89fc212

Comment: @КириллМалышев, мысль интересная, но переполнение при типе int актуально только при миллиарде элементов в массиве, т. е. массив на 4 гигабайта (по 4 байта на элемент). Тут конечно бинарный поиск, но я не думаю, что эта проблема актуальна. К тому же, разве компилятор не оптимизирует всё равно?

Comment: @Qwerty, это просто известный баг из стандартной библиотеки Java. https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html?m=1

Answer (score 4):

1. Бинарный поиск требует максимум **log<sub>2</sub> n** итераций. В этом его прелесть.

   Автор этого кода, очевидно, не сумел сформулировать правильное условие для завершения цикла, а вместо этого поставил счетчик `i`, который насильно "убивает" цикл после `n` итераций. Это безобразие. Зачем нужен бинарный поиск, который делает `n` итераций?

   Улучшить данный код можно аккуратной работой с интервалом `[min, max)` и завершением итераций тогда, когда этот интервал становится пустым. А счетчик `i` - не нужен вообще.
2. Если условия `values[med] > value` и `values[med] < value` не выполняются, то уж наверное явно проверять условие `values[med] == value` смысла нет, а? Ясно, что оно и так верно.

   Это дело вкуса, но я бы в третьей ветке этого `if` вместо проверки условия написал

   ```
   else 
   {
     assert(values[med] == value);
     return true;
   }
   ```
3. Функция, выполняющая бинарный поиск, но в результате дающая лишь `bool` ответ - это разбазаривание полезной информации, полученной в процессе поиска.

   Лучше было бы, если бы такая функция возвращала индекс найденного элемента. А если элемент не найден, то возвращала либо какое-то "особенное" значение (`-1` или `n`), либо позицию для вставки такого элемента в последовательность.

   Если вам при этом захочется еще иметь и `bool` функцию, то ее можно тривиально реализовать в виде надстройки над предыдущей функцией.

Comment: Для этого я и задал данный вопрос. Отдельная благодарность за критику. Щас буду исправлять.

Comment: строго по заданию, дружище

Answer (score 2):

Так ли?

```c
bool binary_search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    //бинарный поиск
    int min, max, mid;
    min = 0;
    max = n-1;
    while(min < max)
    {
        mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if(values[mid] == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(values[mid] > value)
        {
            max = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            min = mid + 1;  
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Вроде нормально. Но замечу, что `max` может становиться `-1`, что для `int` нормально, но при попытке использовать `size_t` код поломается.

Comment: у меня в коде есть проверка на то, что n > 0

Comment: А при чём тут n? Вот так надо: min=0, max=1, mid=0, if (values[mid]>value) max=0-1.

Answer (score 1):

Тут задача довольно своеобразная и требует некоторых логических рассуждений.
Алгоритм бинарного поиска уже предполагает в себе аксиоматику того, что нас массив отсортирован от меньшего числа к большему. Как было правильно сказано, алгоритм требует log операций. Однако отсортированный массив можно использовать в наших целях.
К примеру нам известно, что минимальное число массива A, а максимальное число B. Тогда мы можем в уме создать для себя равномерный массив `[A, A+(B-A)/n, A+2*(B-A)/n, ..., B]`.
Используйте данные соображения, чтобы выбирать более подходящие точки деления. Например, если массив состоит из чисел `[1,3,4,5,8,23]`, а искомое число 3, то массив-маска будет `[1,4,8,12,16,20,23]` к примеру, и точку деления можно взять сразу 2. Код писать не вижу смысла, тут чисто на подумать и сделать.

Comment: А с чего ты взял, что массив примерно равномерный? Есть алгоритм, который работает за гарантированной время, зачем что-то усложнять и городить при том, что в худшем случае результат ухудшится?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, в общем случае распределение  ключей может быть не линейным. Если мы его знаем, то можно это использовать в функции выбора элемента с которым сравниваем. Что касается зачем усложнять, то в случае медленной памяти (например, диск) даже небольшое снижение количества обращений даст приличный выигрыш по абсолютному времени поиска (естественно, если угадали с распределением). В пределе, алгоритм выбора может даже зависить от того в каком из диапазонов последовательности мы проводим поиск в данный момент

Comment: @Qwertiy, ни с чего собственно. Я же привел пример совсем нелинейно распределенного массива. Худшие случаи работы алгоритма разумеется есть. Если тебе не нравится линейное приближение, то используй любую другую функцию, где F(0)=A, F(n-1)=B и все. Можешь взять любой полином с любыми коэффами и примерно с помощью среднего элемента F(n/2)=C предугадать распределение. Человек попросил как-то упростить, улучшить, вот обычный матан в помощь. Будет работать довольно эффективно если массив большой.